# Powershell script to get number of Physical CPU's

Tags: powershell

I tried to get the number of physical CPU's using below script however could not able to get the required resul.

```
get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem
```

Is there any command to get *Number of Physical CPU's* ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/860b8fb9-90ba-4390-ba89-03c253a2c2af/very-simple-code-for-counting-physical-cpus?forum=winserverpowershell) Microsoft question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don Jones in his "Creating HTML Reports in Powershell" [Link](https://www.gitbook.com/book/devops-collective-inc/creating-html-reports-in-powershell/details) book achieved it this way:

```
$cs = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem
$Sockets=$cs.numberofprocessors
$Cores=$cs.numberoflogicalprocessors
```

The output on my pc is:

```
$Sockets
1

$Cores
4
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting in PowerShell 3.0, [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject#description) has been superseded by [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance).

### Number of physical CPUs (a.k.a. sockets)

```
@(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor).Count
```

or:

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfProcessors
```

### Number of physical cores

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property NumberOfCores -Sum).Sum
```

### Number of logical cores

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property NumberOfLogicalProcessors -Sum).Sum
```

or:

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

Answer (score 1):

*If your're looking for properties always use get-member to list them:*

get-wmiobject win32_processor | get-member

*This way you can find properties like:*
NumberOfCores
NumberOfLogicalProcessors

get-wmiobject win32_processor | select-object NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors

Answer (score 0):

In a single line of code:

```
$(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfProcessors
```

There are also other parameters which might interest you such as: NumberOfCores and NumberOfEnabledCore.

For retrieving the all the properties you can run

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object *
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Select-Object *
```

For further reference about each parameter you can check:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor\
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem

Answer (score -1):

Use `Get-WmiObject` or short `gwmi`
To get the instances of the `Win32_Processor` class and then simply count them.

```
$(gwmi Win32_Processor).count
```